GitLab CI fails with "Failed to connect to localhost"
I'm testing out Gitlab CI and I'm trying to understand why I cannot connect to my simple web service container. It appears the container starts, but doesn't listen on the runner, hence the curl test fails.
I'm totally new to GitLab, so I suspect I've just misunderstood something basic. I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me understand what I've missed.
I have a simple Python FastAPI service in a container image. It just runs a simple python script and allows me to query the API.
Thanks for any advice / guidance you can provide.
TL;DR

When I run the container on my local laptop, it's fine.
When I run it on GitLab CI, it fails.
The container runs on GitLab CI, but the webserver doesn't seem to be listening.
I've tried changing ports to no avail.

Here is the output of my run
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/mygroup/myuser/dsaeventserver:dev
registry.gitlab.com/mygroup/myuser/dsaeventserver:dev
$ CTR_ID=$(docker run -d --name test_container -p 8080:80 $IMAGE_NAME)

$ sleep 2

$ docker logs $CTR_ID
INFO     Using path src/swimming.py                                             
INFO     Resolved absolute path /code/src/swimming.py                           
INFO     Searching for package file structure from directories with __init__.py 
         files                                                                  
INFO     Importing from /code/src                                               
                                                                                
 ╭─ Python module file ─╮                                                       
 │                      │                                                       
 │   swimming.py      │                                                       
 │                      │                                                       
 ╰──────────────────────╯                                                       
                                                                                
INFO     Importing module swimming                                              
INFO     Found importable FastAPI app                                           
                                                                                
 ╭── Importable FastAPI app ──╮                                                 
 │                            │                                                 
 │  from swimming import app  │                                                 
 │                            │                                                 
 ╰────────────────────────────╯                                                 
                                                                                
INFO     Using import string swimming:app                                       
                                                                                
 ╭─────────── FastAPI CLI - Production mode ───────────╮                        
 │                                                     │                        
 │  Serving at: http://0.0.0.0:80                      │                        
 │                                                     │                        
 │  API docs: http://0.0.0.0:80/docs                   │                        
 │                                                     │                        
 │  Running in production mode, for development use:   │                        
 │                                                     │                        
 │  fastapi dev                                        │                        
 │                                                     │                        
 ╰─────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯                        
                                                                                
INFO:     Started server process [1]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

$ sleep 10

$ docker image list
REPOSITORY                                                  TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
registry.gitlab.com/mygroup/myuser/dsaeventserver   dev       ff56e284a3eb   About a minute ago   1.09GB

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                   NAMES
5896fc35220b   registry.gitlab.com/mygroup/myuser/dsaeventserver:dev   "fastapi run src/swi…"   15 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp   test_container

$ netstat -ant | egrep -i "listen|established"
Active Internet connections (servers and established)

$ curl http://localhost:8080/docs
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 after 0 ms: Could not connect to server
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 7


This is the test in my gitlab-ci.yml
job test:
  stage: test
  image: docker:latest
  variables:
    APP_PORT: "8080" 
  before_script:
    - apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    # Log into the registry
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    
    # Pull the container image
    - docker pull $IMAGE_NAME
    
    # Run the container, aliasing port 80 to 8080
    - CTR_ID=$(docker run -d --name test_container -p 8080:80 $IMAGE_NAME) 
    - sleep 2
    - docker logs $CTR_ID

    # Give the container some time to start up (optional, depending on the container)
    - sleep 10
    
    # some debug.
    - docker image list 
    - docker ps -a
    - netstat -ant | egrep -i "listen|established"

    # Use curl to check if the container is accessible on port 8080
    - curl http://localhost:8080/docs
    - curl http://localhost:8080/swimmer 
    

My Dockerfile
#
FROM python:3.12
#
WORKDIR /code
#
COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
#
RUN pip install "fastapi[standard]"
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r /code/requirements.txt
#
COPY ./src /code/src
#
CMD ["fastapi", "run", "src/swimming.py", "--port", "80"]

This is the expected output (From my Fedora laptop)
$ docker run -d --name swimapi -p 8080:80 localhost/charmr                                                                                                      
4f70955539c7cd4f48559e9345577c72ae3ca056aeab9435d437b7457e1830f4                                                                                                                                                 

$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/swimmer | head -1                                                                                                                  
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current                                                                                                                                  
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed                                                                                                                                    
100 22216  100 22216    0     0  1485k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1549k                                                                                                                                   
[{"first_name":"David","family_name":"Davis","age":39,"swimming_stroke":"Breaststroke",... etc

I tried to run the container on the runner in GitLab CI, but it fails to listen on port 8080.

its DinD issue , can you try this while running the container in your pipelines - CTR_ID=$(docker run -d --network host --name test_container $IMAGE_NAME)

Thanks Nabin. I tried this change (with and without my -p 8080:80 options). It didn't seem to change anything. The test failed and the ports were still not visible in the netstat.
If you have any other thoughts then that would be awesome. In parallel, I'll try and pull a vanilla NGINX image and test it on that also.

ok let me find if there is anythin elase we can do , but for ci is it possible to build and run everything in the gitlab pipelines??

So I have 2 steps. There is a build stage (which I've not mentioned here as I didn't want to overcomplicate it), this is the test job that runs afterwards.
Did I understand your question correctly ?

can you try using 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost once @Matt  because DinD sometime are pretty trick depending upon where they are deployed. I think this will resolve your issue.

Thanks for the suggestion, that's not changed anything. I'm guessing I might have to register it as some sort of service before the runner will allow me to bind to a port.
I'll also go back through gitlabs documentation to try and understand where I've gone so wrong!

ok let me test myself and get back to you

Thank you, that's really kind.
I'll keep reading the docs in the hope I find my silly mistake.

yeah the first answer is perfect but i could make it work by directly doing curl inside the container that is running in the CI
docker exec test_container curl -v http://localhost:80/docs 
docker exec test_container curl -v http://localhost:80/swimmer

the output in CI:


The issue was that I was trying to use localhost / 127.0.0.1 / 0.0.0.0 to talk to the running container. It appears that the line
  services:
    - docker:dind

actually is the service where my container is running in GitLab CI.
The fix was to point curl at that service.
So I changed
    # Use curl to check if the container is accessible on port 8080
    - curl http://localhost:8080/docs
    - curl http://localhost:8080/swimmer 

to use
    # Use curl to check if the container is accessible on port 8080
    - curl http://docker:8080/docs
    - curl http://docker:8080/swimmer

and it worked perfectly.
This video helped me understand it better.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fymJsLIwrFU
Massive thanks to Nabin for trying to help me.

it was my pleasure , i did  find another way to curl the api though, thank you for giving me new scenario to improve my skill
